# Google's search suggest XHR requests

Tags: javascript, ajax, firebug, xmlhttprequest

I went to google, and had my firebug open. I started typing "in", and then checked the "NET" tab of Firebug, and a couple of new GET requests had been sent to fetch the list of search autocomplete suggestions.

Like:

```
GET http://clients1.google.com/complete/search?hl=en&client=hp&expIds=17259,17315,23628,24549,26637,26761,26849,26869,27386,27404&q=i&cp=1
```

But they were classified under the "JS" section, rather than as a "XHR" - why is this? Isn't google making an AJAX GET request behind the scene?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is almost certainly a [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP) request, used to get around cross-domain restrictions on XHRs. Essentially, they are dynamically inserting `<script />` tags into their page, and that's why it shows up under JS in Firebug.